# Error in cloning from github

Tags: github

I am trying to clone a repository from github but havn't been able to successfully do so. Please help.I am getting

```
gaurav@gaurav-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500:~$ git clone https://github.com/gauravp94/eden.git
Cloning into 'eden'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/gauravp94/eden.git/': Failed connect to github.com:1080; Connection timed out
```

I am running internet thorough my college proxy on Ubuntu 13.10.
Thanks.

Comment: try to download it as zip file from the web page

Answer (score 2):

Your clone command is valid and working, so basically you seem to have either network problem, dns problem, routing problem or you just tried in moment github was doing something:

```
Failed connect to github.com:1080; Connection timed out
```

It works for me, so try again.

Answer (score 0):

The url

https://github.com/gauravp94/eden.git/

is not accessible. Please try opening this url in browser IE. Check if you have access to this url.

Comment: I can view the page, I am using Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Please check in IE. Because command prompt uses ie connection.